# Range hood wall vent offset with 8 inch run

Tags: kitchens, ventilation

We bought a under cabinet range hood with a six inch round connection. The existing ventilation goes outside through a 3 1/4” by 10” horizontal vent cut quite close at about 11” from the top of the range hood to the top of the vent. The problem is that the vent was cut open with approximately two inches of horizontal offset.

To accommodate such a short run, I believe the only option is to construct customized rectangular ductwork to deal with this offset.

Would a simple rectangular trapezoidal box approximately 8” deep x 14” wide x 7-8” tall work?  There would be a 6 inch collar installed at the bottom of the box to connect with the range hood. Then a 3 1/4” by 10” opening would be cut in the box to vent outside.

Other than the drop in suction and turbulence/noise, how bad of an idea is this?  Are there any better options?  Is this even safe or code compliant?

One alternative considered:

Alternative 1  (described from range hood to exterior wall vent)

1. A straight six inch round pipe extending up about 7 or 8 inches
2. 6 inch collar
3. Collar installed in the bottom of 3 1/4  tall x 14 wide x 8 deep box
4. Box mounted to interior cabinet wall over the exterior vent.

Edit: Below are pictures of the existing duct likely installed by the builder.

[image: front view of offset]

[image: bottom width]

[image: top width illustrating offset]

[image: height]

[image: depth]

[image: range hood]

Comment: Despite the pictures and description, I am not following it.  If you use something the manufacturer does not like, then you run the risk of losing your warranty and your insurance claim.  Are you not able to enlarge the hole so that the duct/flue is straight and cover the extra space in some fashion?

Comment: Rohit the TLDR is as follows: Existing ventilation above the cooktop uses a standard rectangular size.  We are replacing our microwave and installing a range hood with a 6" round connection.  The existing rectangular vent is offset making it difficult to use off the shelf connections and ductwork.  Custom ducting will be required.  I am seeking advice on the best/easiest way to safely connect the new range hood.  Modifying the existing vents is possible but only a last resort.  Thanks.

Comment: Rohit, modifying the exhaust duct is essentially what I am proposing.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with using a 3-1/4x10" to 6" round stack boot, like this? https://www.homedepot.com/p/Master-Flow-10-in-x-3-1-4-in-to-6-in-90-Degree-Stack-Boot-90SB10X3-25X6/100174597

Comment: Huesmann, the issue is that the exhaust vent is not centered and is offset by between two and three inches.  WIth such a short distance between the wall exhaust vent and range hood connection, it's impossible to use off the shelf connections with rigid duct.  I'm proceeding forward by constructing a custom rectangular duct with cut to size galvanized steel sheet. It should have approximately the same profile as the stack boot you linked.  It'll just be a couple inches longer with a horizontally offset round connection.